# How can I use vba to tell if an Active X combobox on an excel sheet has an a list

Tags: vba, excel, combobox

How can I use vba to tell if an Active X combobox on an excel sheet has a list with items in it.

The following returns an error if the combobox has nothing in it's list:

```
if UBound(MyComboBox.List, 1) > 1 then
```

and the following returns an error if there are items in the list:

```
if MyComboBox.List <> Null then
```

Cheers!

Oliver.

Comment: Isn't there a .ListCount property you could use?

Comment: There is! And it does the job! Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code with check if there are items in the ComboBox1 and list all the items it finds:

```
Dim lngRow As Long

If ComboBox1.ListCount > 0 Then
    For lngRow = 0 To ComboBox1.LineCount - 1
        Debug.Print ComboBox1.List(lngRow , 0)
    Next intRow
End If
```

Comment: I upvoted this, but I'd change your counter to a `Long` as a ComboBox can have more than 32k items.

Comment: Amazing! .ListCount was what I was after! Cheers!